# Configuring a FineUpload instance

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload, fine-uploader

I have the following basic setup for an uploader:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
         element: $('#fine-uploader')[0],
         request: {
            endpoint: 'server/handleUploads'
         },
         autoUpload: true,
         multiple: false,
         text: {
            uploadButton: '<asp:Button ID="btnFineUploader" runat="server" style="margin-right:7px;width:65px;" Text="Browse" CssClass="button" />'
         },
         validation: {
            allowedExtensions: ['mp3', 'wav'],
         }
      });
   });
</script>

<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
```

This generates the following:

[image: current appearance]

Now that I at least have the uploader rendering I'm working on making it look/behave in a specific manner.  Here's some things I'm trying to accomplish:

- I don't want to display "Processing dropped files" (it displays all the time, even before I select/upload a file)
- I don't want "RetryDeleteUpload failed" to display to the right of the file name
- I don't want the uploaded filename to appear as a bullet below the button, but rather right to the right of it
- I don't want multiple files to be uploaded, but settings the limit size to 1 also doesn't accompslish what I want -- I want to be able to select/upload a second file that *replaces* the first one (i.e. I don't get an error, I just replace the previous upload)

Also, this is probably very simple, but how do I wire the endpoint to something in my ASP.NET code-behind?  Add a method "void handleUploads()"?

Also, will the fact that I wrapped the uploadButton with an asp:Button cause breakage in IE (I did it just to get default CSS style applied to that).

Thanks.  Hopefully I can wrap this up, get licensed and deploy soon.

EDIT:  Yes, I've checked out the docs on github, and many of the settings for FileUploader mode are simply not working.

Comment: Please show ALL of your HTML/imports.

Comment: ...I ask this as it seems likely that you are simply not including the correct files in the head section of your HTML file.

Comment: As per your recommendation in the last post, I fixed my imports (in this case `<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>`), and now the control is actually rendering.  At this point is just about massaging the parameters I place into `qq.FineUploader(...)`, as well as learning how to link this in the code behind.

Comment: Ok.  It isn't clear if you have a specific question at this point relating to your original post.  If this is true, you should probably just delete your question and create any new ones that you have in the future.  Otherwise, please edit your question appropriately.

Comment: My question is the four bullet points after the screencap of what fineuploader currently displays/does.  I want my instance to meet those behaviors.  Besides that, I was also asking how to access the `server/handleUploads` in ASP.NET code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with your ASP code, but I can point you at the .NET examples in the server-side examples repo, as well as the server-side readme (which you should have encountered when going through the documentation).

Your first three questions exist because you have not imported the default CSS file into your document.  If you import that properly, you will see that these questions no longer have any meaning.

For your 4th bullet-point, set the `multiple` option to "false" as you have already done in your code above.

Comment: In going through the github page under fine-updater/docs I didn't see the server-side read me, link?  Thanks, multiple works well.  Do you know how to make (referring to the screencap above) the strings "Processing dropped files..." and "RetryDeleteUpload Failed" not visible?

Comment: They should not all be visible by default when the uploader loads.  There is likely some javascript error in your project or perhaps you are not importing Fine Uploader's default CSS file into your document.  The link for the server-side documentation is currently [here](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader-server/blob/master/readme.md).  In 3.6, I will include a better documented reference section in the main readme to make finding these documents easier.

Comment: I looked into a CSS problem, and it turns out in the dev console in Chrome I am getting a `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`.  This error corresponds to the period at the beginning of CSS file: `.qq-upload {`.  So the CSS is getting imported, it's just erroring out.

Comment: That doesn't sound correct.  There are no syntax errors in any Fine Uploader files.  It sounds like you have some issue in your client-side code/setup.  You'll need to spend some time sorting this out, as I can't tell where you are going wrong exactly.  Posting all of your HTML would be helpful, perhaps.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't release my code.  After looking through the server examples, I notice that only the code-behind is shown.  This doesn't do much to help explain how the aspx and code-behind match up.  Do you have available any extremely basic full projects available for download?

Comment: There are numerous demos of client-side code on the home page.  Start with the "setup" example.

Comment: I apologize because I'm probably being a pain in the neck at this point, but I need markup code that matches a specific code-behind.  That's the only way I'll get this working.  It's quite hard to understand the link between the `request/endpoint` piece and code-behind in the absence of an example (especially when they are split up over two websites.)